# Should I ask user to provide password then he/she signs up with Facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, access-token, facebook-access-token

I have a mobile application that supports classic login (with email/password) and facebook login. In case of facebook login, I wonder if user can skip entering the password ?

In more detail, the user table will just have email, password_hash (optional field).

All the interactions user does with the system will be via a token (not the facebook token) that the server sends back.

After when user logs in (on a different device for example) via Facebook button, the server will check their account by querying user email in graph API using user's facebook token. The returned email will be checked against the email provided by user. If they are equal, a token is created and sent back to client.

So the schema will be

1. Client (mobile app):

   - user clicks 'log in'
   - app gets facebook_token and email.
   - App sends this token and email to server
2. Server:

   - uses the facebook_token to get user email from graph API.
   - if returned email == provided email, create a token and send it back to client.
3. Client: receive the token and do all the transaction with this token.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The user cannot skip entering a password if they aren't logged into Facebook.

The app should **never** ask a user for his/her password. OAuth exists for this reason.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if what I proposed is kind of standard or is there better way to handle that ?